# Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pip, environment

> File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 655, in get_mathlib_info
> raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
> RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

Running python 3.9 64 bit
W10

Trying to pip install numpy through the command prompt.

I found two recommended solutions and I've tried both

I installed windows sdk and added mt.exe to the path
I also installed Visual Studio 2019.

Problem still persists.

Comment: I think need to try with python 3.8

Comment: Python 3.9 has only just been released. Use `pip install pipwin`, then `pipwin install numpy` for now, to get the binary wheels provided by Gohlke, until Numpy builds wheels for 3.9.

Comment: holy crap thank you Martjin; finally found the right solution after hours of trying to install numpy. Why is it so hard to install numpy...